# When a quotation is interrupted by someone finishing the quotation's sentence, should the second part be capitalized?

Tags: capitalization, quotations

My question has to do with the following example:

> “And remember to turn off the stove after using it in the mornings,
> and—”
>
> “Put up all the ingredients,” I finished for my mother with a
> little bit of a smirk. “I know, Mom; I won’t forget.”

Should the word *put* be capitalized in the second line? Thanks!

Comment: This is literature we are considering and a case not envisaged in the rules for quotation marks.  So I would say it is up to you.  Because the problem is rare and whatever you do will look odd to someone.  I myself would replace the dash with three dots and begin the interruption with three dots and a lower case ‘p’.  I would argue that this captures the continuity better.  But that’s my personal view.  There is no rule or evidence base to which I can appeal.

Comment: I would normally agree with what Tuffy is saying; however, this seems to be an interruption, and does not work well with ellipsis, which normally  sounds like a pause or trailing off. For me...I would use the m dashes to end and start. The most important would be how you think it should sound in natural conversation.

Comment: This is more of a style issue, and probably POB. You could look over at https://writing.stackexchange.com/

Comment: I *personally* prefer the example exchange as it's written. (Where it's clear that I'm actually *interrupting* my mother—which is the function of the dash. If I were *continuing* her sentence after she *paused*, I would punctuate it differently—such as with an ellipsis. However, that would change the sense of the exchange.) But there is no rule.

Comment: So, @Cascabel, would you write it like the following?

_“And remember to turn off the stove after using it in the mornings, and—” [linebreak]
“—put up all the ingredients,” I finished for my mother with a little bit of a smirk. “I know, Mom; I won’t forget.”_

Comment: I guess, but it is your words, in your voice, in your ear. Think about what ellipsis, quotes, m dashes, and full stops sound like _when spoken._ It is a style issue. Lemme know when you publish.

Comment: @Cascabel I'm going to go with that suggestion. Actually, I'm editing, not authoring, a book. It's the second in the series. If you'd like to read the first, it can be found here: [link](https://www.amazon.com/Arlington-Aquarian-Mystery-Secrets-Abandoned-ebook/dp/B07D3GBJN5/ref=tmm_kin_swatch_0?_encoding=UTF8&qid=1526592794&sr=8-1).

Comment: @Cascabel Also, I'm new here, so how do I mark an answer as being the one I used? I want to mark your first comment as such. Thanks!

Comment: @Cascabel While editing the third book right now, I came back to this thread and was reminded that you said, "Lemme know when you publish." Sorry I forgot to say anything before, but the book's been published, and here's a link: https://www.amazon.com/Kodiak-Nobleman-Mystery-Secrets-Abandoned-ebook/dp/B07VKDPPKN/ref=sr_1_1?dchild=1&keywords=kodiak+nobleman&qid=1612493550&s=digital-text&sr=1-1

Comment: Thanks for the link...there is no way of checking my answer  off, as it was only a comment. I won't post a real answer here because the material on punctuation has been covered many times before.